# Creating shape from the opposite direction

Tags: adobe-photoshop

Is it possible to create with custom shape tool, but from the opposite direction While dragging?
photoshop CS5
Thank you
Yod
[image]

Comment: ... not that I'm aware of

Answer (score 1):

Photoshop doesn't work that way because of how custom shapes are created and stored in that program.

The workaround is to draw the shape, press Ctl-T for Free Transform, right click and choose "Rotate 180", then adjust from there.